# SSRS matrix - How to add total per year in SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I do have SSRS matrix as below, and it will include for column group months for current year, for row group it does have current and future months (in my case it's for 2 years):

| current with future months | current year months |
| --- | --- |
| current with future months | Sum(Values) |

I want to add total to sum Values per year and show right after December month. Example in below table. Idk is this possible to do in SSRS

Output :

| current with future months | Jan 2022 | Feb 2022 | Mar 2022 | and till.. | Dec 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2022 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| Feb 2022 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| Mar 2022 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| ... till | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| Dec 2022 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| **2022 Total** | **Total Jan** | **Total Feb** | **Total March** | **Total...** | **Total Dec** |
| Jan 2023 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| Feb 2023 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| Mar 2023 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| ... till | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| Dec 2023 | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) | Sum(Values) |
| **2023 Total** | **Total Jan** | **Total Feb** | **Total March** | **Total...** | **Total Dec** |

Basically I want to show Totals for 2 years separately just after December for each year.

Note: I was able to do/get total for each year in the end of table, but I need after each December.

Comment: You will need row and column groups that group by year, then simply add totals to those row and column groups by right-clicking the group names in the groups panel and choose "Add Total"

Comment: @Alan Thanks. But didn't get it. I do table from DB which when I use matrix in SSRS I already did row group on field "current year and future" (2years months) and column group on "Current year months". Now I have table in SSRS which got populated with that matrix ( table below without Bold rows). I did 1 more Row group and got 2 years - totals, but their both in the bottom of table.